# unique username generator

Tags: python

I have written a class to generate a unique username from the full name. The full name is the name of a company usually containing 4 to 5 words. The username generated will be of format {preffix}{username}{suffix}. The user name should not be derived from stop words. stops words are generated analysing the most common words in the list of companies name.

To generate name I am taking the first letter from each word of name and taking remaining from the last word. For eg. if the length of the username is 5 then *ABC Company Limited* will be converted to *ACLIM*.

kindly review the code.

```
class UniqueNameGenerator:

    def __init__(self, stop_words, suffix, prefix):

        self.stop_words = stop_words
        self.suffix = suffix
        self.prefix = prefix

    def split_full_name_and_filter_stop_word(self, full_name, size):

        name_words = " ".join(full_name.split(" ")).split()

        if len(name_words) > size:
            name_words = name_words[:size]
        words_considered = []
        for word in name_words:
            ignore_word = False
            if word.lower() in self.stop_words:
                ignore_word = True
            if not ignore_word:
                words_considered.append(word)
        return words_considered

    @staticmethod
    def get_name_from_list_of_words(size, list_of_words):

        size_counter = 1
        len_words_considered = len(list_of_words)
        letters_left = size
        username = ""
        while size_counter <= len_words_considered:
            current_word = list_of_words[size_counter - 1]
            if size_counter == len_words_considered:
                if len(current_word) >= letters_left:
                    username += current_word[:letters_left]
                else:
                    username += current_word
            else:
                username += current_word[0]
                letters_left -= 1
            size_counter += 1
        return username

    def check_and_update_username_to_unique(self, username, unique_name_list):

        while True:
            s = len(username)
            if username in unique_name_list:
                char_list = list(username)
                char_list[random.randint(0, s)] = random.choices(
                    string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
                )[0]
                username = "".join(char_list)
            else:
                return username

    def generate_username(self, full_name, size, unique_name_list=None):

        if not unique_name_list:
            unique_name_list = []

        full_name = re.sub("[^\sa-zA-Z]+", "", full_name)
        words_considered = self.split_full_name_and_filter_stop_word(full_name, size)
        username = self.get_name_from_list_of_words(size, words_considered)
        if self.suffix:
            username = username + self.suffix
        if self.prefix:
            username = self.prefix + username
        username = self.check_and_update_username_to_unique(username, unique_name_list)
        return username
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by _stop words_? Some clarification on the whole _full name_ vs _username_ vs _name_ would be good, too. For example, the sentence _The username generated will be of format {preffix}{username}{suffix}._ seems to indicate some sort of recursion in the `username`.

Comment: what should be the result for `full_name= 'ABC Company Limited'` and `size=2` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Good question. In the same vein, what would the username be for `full_name= 'ABC Company Limited'` and `size=10+`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest username should be 'ac'.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile currently it would print only 'abclimited'. I missed this case.

Comment: @JoshiR Can you elaborate on the algorithm as a whole? It’s tough to comment on the code without knowing exactly what it’s supposed to do.

Comment: stop words are the words which should be filtered out from full name while generating a username. ex. 'the', 'and' etc.
Logic I am using is first filtering out stop words. From filtered words, I am picking a letter from each word. And from last word I am picking remaining letters. This is to keep username similar to full name. Also, I shall handle the case you mentioned in the previous comment by appending some random numeric to the username. At last, I am checking for unique word from the list of existing unique names.

Comment: {preffix}{username}{suffix} is to indicate prefix + username + suffix. prefix and suffix will be provided to the function in case they are required by user.

Comment: @JoshiR _At last, I am checking for unique word from the list of existing unique names_ Could you rephrase this? What do you mean by _unique word_ versus _unique names_? Is this just checking the uniqueness of the “username” part (without the prefix or suffix)?

Comment: I am checking the uniqueness of with prefix and suffix. unique_name_list is a list of the existing names. username returned by this function (with prefix and suffix) should not be in unique_name_list.

Comment: @JoshiR Alright. If it isn’t unique, it looks like you randomly change a single character, is that correct?

Comment: yes. Replacing with random character at random position.

Comment: @JoshiR Would you be open to slight changes in the algorithm? For example, instead of changing characters randomly until it works, why not append a number sequence to every otherwise identical username?

Comment: there should be some similarity between full name and username.

Comment: @JoshiR Absolutely, which is why I asked about adding a unique number instead of changing characters randomly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**#### Areas to fix/improve:**

***Namings***

The function names like `split_full_name_and_filter_stop_word`, `check_and_update_username_to_unique` and alike are considered as *anti-patterns* for function naming.
`run_and_fly` or `think_or_talk` like names point to ambiguity or excessive responsibilities assigned to a function.
A function should have a concrete responsibility. Therefore, you need to analyze those functions and apply whether *Rename function* or *Extract function* (in your case - split a function into several functions each with separate responsibility) technique.

Some variable and function names are too verbose:
`name_words` --> just `names`
`get_name_from_list_of_words` --> just `compose_username`
`list_of_words` --> just a plural `words`
`unique_name_list` --> just `unique_names`

---

**`def generate_username(self, full_name, size, unique_name_list=None)`** method.

- to avoid passing the same `unique_name_list` across multiple methods - it's good to pass it into `UniqueNameGenerator` constructor at once.
- `full_name = re.sub("[^\sa-zA-Z]+", "", full_name)`. In case if `full_name` happened to be empty, to avoid redundant calls of subsequent functions - it's good to add a check for that:

  ```
  ...
  full_name = re.sub("[^\sa-z]+", "", full_name.strip(), re.I)
  if not full_name:
      raise ValueError(f'Incorrect full name `{full_name}`')
  ```
- either of these complements:

  ```
  if self.suffix:
      username = username + self.suffix
  if self.prefix:
      username = self.prefix + username
  ```

  can throw `TypeError` in case if caller would pass non-string argument for `prefix` or `suffix`.
  Instead, use flexible `f-string` formatting:

  ```
  username = f'{self.prefix}{username}{self.suffix}'
  ```

---

**`def split_full_name_and_filter_stop_word(self, full_name, size)`** method

- the function name is better named as `filter_valid_words` or `select_valid_words` (or alike)
- `" ".join(full_name.split(" ")).split()` - this looks like a "5-wheel bicycle that circles rounds instead of going *straight*".
  Simply `words = full_name.split()`
- the whole construction:

  ```
  words_considered = []
  for word in name_words:
      ignore_word = False
      if word.lower() in self.stop_words:
          ignore_word = True
      if not ignore_word:
          words_considered.append(word)
  ```

  is a verbose "invention" of a simple list comprehension with `if` constraint:

  ```
  valid_words = [w for w in words if w.lower() not in self.stop_words]
  ```

  The restructured function would look as:

  ```
  def filter_valid_words(self, full_name, size):
      words = full_name.split()
      if len(words) > size:
          words = words[:size]

      return [w for w in words if w.lower() not in self.stop_words]
  ```